# How to create different singleton instances in different class loaders?

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

I have an application that uses a ClassLoader hierarchy to run plugins. We have one parent ClassLoader at the "server" level and then child ClassLoaders for each plugin. Each plugin gets access to a few services that are dedicated to that plugin, and I would like to provide access via a singleton.

```
public class PluginServices {
    private static PluginServices _instance = null;
    private PluginServices() {
    }
    public static PluginServices getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new PluginServices();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static Service1 getService1() { ... }        
    public static Service2 getService2() { ... }        

}
```

However, when I access the singleton from the plugins, I am always getting the same instance instead of a new one per plugin. It seems like this is occurring because the .class for PluginServices is located in a JAR that is loaded by the Parent ClassLoader, and so the instance is tied to that ClassLoader instead of my plugin ClassLoaders.

Is there any way that I can have the PluginServices Singleton instance tied to the plugin's ClassLoader and therefore each plugin would get its own instance?

Comment: You would have to find the singleton class in the class loader, and create an instance with `newInstance`.  But, of course, that kinda negates the singletonness of it all.  Or you could find the class and then use reflections to access the singleton access method -- probably a little better.

Comment: That kind of is the point of a Singleton, making sure there is only one instance of it.

Comment: (Of course you'd need to create singleton to contain the pointer to the singleton you created.)